# Android Kotlin Volley How to send JSON Data

Tags: android, json, rest, kotlin, android-volley

I want to use Volley send JSON payload to REST API. But I get an error

"com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Payload from Magento
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/inventory/create-cart-add-products.html

> JSON Payload

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "10-1001",
    "qty": 5,
    "quote_id": "3"
  }
}
```

> Volley Code

```
// Create JSON
val itemsObject = JSONObject()
itemsObject.put("sku", "10-1001")
itemsObject.put("qty", 5)
itemsObject.put("quote_id", "3")

val itemsArray = JSONObject()
itemsArray.put("cartItem", itemsObject)


val jsonRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.POST, url, itemsArray,

        Response.Listener { response ->

            try {

                binding.txtStatus.text = response.toString()

            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                binding.txtStatus.text = e.toString()
            }

        },

        Response.ErrorListener { error ->

            binding.txtStatus.text = error.toString()

        }) {
        @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
        override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
            return "application/json"
        }

        override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
            val apiHeader = HashMap<String, String>()
            apiHeader["Authorization"] = "Bearer $cusToken"
            return apiHeader
        }

    }

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)
    queue.add(jsonRequest)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject`. Your `itemsArray` must be like this:

`val itemsArray = JSONArray()`

Your request payload must look like this and can have multiple objects:

```
[
   {
      "sku":"10-1001",
      "qty":5,
      "quote_id":"3"
   },
   {
      "sku":"10-1002",
      "qty":1,
      "quote_id":"2"
   }
]
```

The reason is because the payload now contains multiple items. You can add multiple `JSONObject` in the `JSONArray`.

Another approach can be if you want to send some other information in the request payload then you might need to use in the following manner:

```
{
   "cartItems":[
      {
         "sku":"10-1001",
         "qty":5,
         "quote_id":"3"
      },
      {
         "sku":"10-1002",
         "qty":1,
         "quote_id":"2"
      }
   ],
   "otherInfo":"sampleInfo"
}
```

Comment: I can't change the type of payload this is Magento payload
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/inventory/create-cart-add-products.html